# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is notiterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am write a python code to list all the words in a file.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
word = list()
for line in fh:
    lst = line.split()
    for w in lst :
        if not w in word :
            word = word.append(w)
word = word.sort()
print(word)
```

Why does it show

```
> if not w in word : 
> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is notiterable
```

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `word` into a `None`, as `word.append(w)` returns `None` (or to be exact, it does not return anything).

Replace `word = word.append(w)` with `word.append(w)`

Edit -
Same issue will happen with your `word = word.sort()`, should replace it with `word.sort()`.